# asymptotics of primes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-number-theorem

If $a$ and $q$ are given coprime positive integers, what is the best known error term for 
$$
\sum_{p<x,\,p\,\text{is prime},\,p\equiv a \pmod q} \frac{\log p}p-\frac{\log x}{\varphi(q)}?
$$
Is it, say, proven to be $O(1)$?

Comment: Yes it is $O(1)$.  You can see this by using the Brun-Titchmarsh theorem (and partial summation) to bound the sum over primes in the range $x\le \exp(\phi(q))$, and then using the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions and partial summation for all larger $x$.

Comment: One more remark: it is hard to avoid the error term $O(1)$ since it may happen for example that $a$ is itself a small prime.  If you omit this first term, that is sum over $q<p\le x$ then one should be able to get better error terms.

Comment: Well, in my situation $q$ is given, so I wonder only about large values of $x$. But indeed, it just follows from any reasonable remainder estimate in PNT for arithmetic progressions.